# can i make view of views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how can make view of more than one views 6.Please give me solution.Is any module in drupal 6.If it is not then how to customiz the view so that we make view of views.
I enable the view module and homebox module.pls gv me solution.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking for here. Try rewording your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a list of views, the simplest option is to create each View as a block and place all the blocks on the same page.

Other alternatives are:

- Views attachments (see http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/drupal6-attachment-display-views)
- [Viewfield module](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield)

  > Viewfield provides a field that holds a reference to a View and
  >   renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.
- adding a View area as part of the header/footer of a view (only available in D7, I think) -- see http://drupal.org/files/vfv-cant-select-display.jpg

Comment: Is there is any video for viewfield module.pls gv me.